# html text box form that will not allow input

Tags: html

Is there any class in an html form that does not allow you to input or change the value in that text box. But you can see its content , for example the code below will allow you to see the content of the record in mysql database. But what I want is for it not to be edited.
What would I add to the code below so that its content will not be editted by the users:

```
   <tr>
<td><font size="3">Civil Status</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="cs" type="text" maxlength="7" value="<?php echo $row["CSTAT"]; ?>"></td>
<td><font size="3">Age</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="age" type="text" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo $row["AGE"]; ?>"></td>
<td><font size="3">Birthday</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="bday" type="text" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $row["BDAY"]; ?>"></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><font size="3">Address</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="ad" type="text" maxlength="25" value="<?php echo $row["ADDRESS"]; ?>"></td>
<td><font size="3">Telephone #</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="telnum" type="text" maxlength="11" value="<?php echo $row["TELNUM"]; ?>"></td>

<td width="23"><font size="3">Sex</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="174"><input name="sex" type="text"  maxlength="1" value="<?php echo $row["SEX"]; ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What about the [readonly attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)?

```
<input type="text" name="telnum" value="123456" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 15):

You can put `readonly="readonly"` in your `<input>` tag.  You can also use `disabled="disabled"`.  Both provide varying degrees of "disabled-ness" as [demonstrated here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_DISABLED.html).

This is not fail-safe, though.  Make sure that you do check when the form is POSTed back if the value has been modified - someone can craft a valid POST request with the field value modified - there's nothing you can do about that except check on the server-side if it's been modified from what it was originally.

Comment: The addendum about checking the value on the backend is very important.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want it edited, and if there's no reason for it ever to *be* edited, then it shouldn't be in an `input` element at all. Just echo it as normal text.

Comment: Good input, but doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can try "**disabled**" OR "**readonly**"

```html
<form> 
  <label for="disabled">Disabled</label><br> 
  <input name="disabled" value="disabled" disabled>
  <br><br>
  <label for="readonly">Read Only</label><br> 
  <input name="readonly" value="readonly" readonly> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

use readonly

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Answer (score 2):

Use the readonly attribute

```
<input readonly="value" />
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp