# How to fix form that will not allow text to be entered?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, semantic-ui-react

### Background

Ever since I added a Switch statement in React-Router, I have lost functionality in my form. I cannot type in the input box and, as a result cannot add new items to my database. Before this happened, I was able to do a fetch post with no issues.

While I was researching, I looked through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355450/html-text-box-form-that-will-not-allow-input) on inputs, but it's not quite what I need since I **want** my input to accept text.

The form has local state, but I tried `mapStateToProps` just in case that was an issue. There, I can see in my React tools that the input is being captured (albeit only one character before it rerenders).

### Code

Here is the container where my routes are set up.

```
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={(routerProps) => <Programs {...routerProps} programs={this.props.programs}/>} /> />
          <Route exact path='/programs' render={(routerProps) => <Programs {...routerProps} programs={this.props.programs}/>} />
          <Route path='/programs/new' render={(routerProps) => <ProgramInput {...routerProps} />}/>
          <Route path='/programs/:id' render={(routerProps) => <Program {...routerProps} programs={this.props.programs}/>}/>
          <Route exact path='/watchlist' render={(routerProps) => <Watchlist {...routerProps} programs={this.props.programs} />} />
        </Switch>
```

Here is one of the three inputs I have on my form. They are all identical except for the label and value.

```
        <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  label='Name'
                  value={this.state.name}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  width={6} />
```

Here is the handleChange method referenced in my input.

```
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }
```

### My Goal

I'd like to restore the functionality of my form so I/the user can get back to adding items to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to define a name property on the input

```
   <Form.Input
       fluid
       name="name"
       label='Name'
       value={this.state.name}
       onChange={this.handleChange}
       width={6} />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Of course! I redesigned this form a few times and must have removed that property. Smh. Thank you SO much for your help. :-)

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us!